# Javascript object members

Tags: javascript

```
var math = {

    Factorial:function(n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return n * Factorial(n - 1);
    },

    CalculateFactorial:function() {
        var myValue = document.getElementById('myTextBox').value;
        if (myValue.length == 0) {
            alert("Please input the correct value!");
            return;
        }
        var result = Factorial(myValue);
        document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = result;
    }

}
```

Hello guys. New to JavaScript and testing different things, coming from C# language things are pretty the same yet different.

I am trying to do something and no success.

Having the script above attached to a simple html button , trying to call the CalculateFactorial , math.CalculateFactorial(); , but what is wierd is that CalculateFactorial() doesn't actually see the Factorial() method. But in the math object I can see both methods. Wierd.

"JavaScript runtime error: 'Factorial' is undefined"

Comment: do `math.Factorial()`

Comment: `Factorial` and `CalculateFactorial` are **properties** of an object. `Factorial(myValue)` tries to read the **variable** `Factorial`, which doesn't exist. Properties are not variables and properties do not magically become variables in methods. The functions you assign to `Factorial` and `CalculateFactorial` don't even know that they are properties of `math`. Functions are first-class citizens in JavaScript, they are independent values.

Comment: No no , I wanna call the CalculateFactorial() since it has the whole logic there , this is the way I want to call it , I know it's not elegant but testing things , trying to Call math.CalculateFactorial() and CalculateFactorial is dependent on Factorial() but for some reason it does not see it.

Comment: *"but for some reason it does not see it"* Because that's not how JavaScript works (see my previous comment). Properties are pretty much independent from each other. I highly recommend to read https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS if you want to get a good understanding of JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Felix , as I said I am new to JS no idea how things work and how to create a proper object , trying to figure out how to make this method call.

Comment: sidenote: your value is going to be a string when you get it from the textbox so I think you need to parse it into an int

Comment: The object you created is fine. You are just not calling the functions/methods properly. Again, there is no function `Factorial`. There is the *property* `math.Factorial` and that's what you have to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good practice in JavaScript is to name all of your functions even if you assign them to a variable or use them like object's property. In your case just give a name to your `Factorial` function like this:

```
Factorial:function factorial(n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return n * factorial(n - 1);
},
```

For the problem of not seeing `Factorial` in your `CalculateFactorial` function just use `this.Factorial` when you invoke it.

Comment: @MihailGeorgescu: You still have to replace `Factorial(myValue)` with `math.Factorial(myValue)` or `this.Factorial(myValue)`.

Comment: I edited my answer with solution to the second problem. :)

Comment: And yes how Felix said , that only solved part of my problem.

Comment: You still get an error after using `this.Factorial(myValue)` in your `CalculateFactorial` function?

Comment: Yes " JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'factorial' " using factorial because that's what I named the Factorial property , if I call the function by Factorial it throws me an undefined error.

Comment: I just ran this code: `var math = {
    Factorial:function factorial(n)
    {
        if (n == 0)
        {
   return 1;
        }

  return n * factorial(n - 1);
    },

    CalculateFactorial:function() {
  var myValue = document.getElementById('myTextBox').value;
  if (myValue.length == 0) {
   alert("Please input the correct value!");
   return;
  }
  
  var result = this.Factorial(myValue);
  document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = result;
 }
}` and it's working great for me.

Comment: Indeed that works and I am glad! The main problem was that in the recursive method I was actually calling the Factorial not factorial with lower case f . hehe anyway , I am glad we figured it out! +1 sir!

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the issue... if you want Factorial to be an internal only function (just a utility for the exposed CalculateFactorial) then you can do so this way:

```
var math = new function() {
      var $this = this;

      var Factorial = function(n) {
          if (n == 0) {
              return 1;
          }

          return n * Factorial(n - 1);
      }

      $this.CalculateFactorial = function() {
          var myValue = document.getElementById('myTextBox').value;

          if (myValue.length == 0) {
              alert("Please input the correct value!");
              return;
          }
          var result = Factorial(myValue);
          document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = result;

      }

  }
```

The deeper design issue here is this is not particularly reusable javascript.  You should consider pulling CalculateFactorial() out of the math object and into it's own handler... probably a click handler would be my guess like this:

```
  var math = new function() {
      var $this = this;

      $this.Factorial = function(n) {
          if (n == 0) {
              return 1;
          }

          return n * $this.Factorial(n - 1);
      }
  }

 $("#calcButton").click(function() {
    var myValue = document.getElementById('myTextBox').value;

    if (myValue.length == 0) {
        alert("Please input the correct value!");
        return;
    }
    var result = math.Factorial(myValue);
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = result;
 })
```

Comment: Yea I will try to redesign this and pull that function out of there. Thank you for the answer. Just trying things out.

Comment: Awesome! Good luck... there is a great book called "Maintainable Javascript" by Nicholas Zakas.  I highly recommend it.  He also has some wonderful talks on youtube :)

Comment: Thank you sir! Well yea , at the moment following some tutorials made by Bob Tabor , the dude is amazing if you don't already know him , also thank you again for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

That happens beceause the `Factorial` method is part of the `math` object, and it doesn't reside in the global scope. When you try to call it directly, the parser will try to find that method into the global scope, and then, it will thrown an `ReferenceError`.

Since you're using the method inside the object itself, you can use the `this` keyword, because it will look into the object's context and find the method `Factorial`.

Another way of calling the `Factorial` method is by using the object, e.g: `math.Factorial`.

Take a look at the example below:

```js
var math = {
  Factorial: function(n) {
    return n === 0 ? 1 : n * this.Factorial(n - 1);
  },

  CalculateFactorial: function(txt) {
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = this.Factorial(txt.value);
  }
};

document.getElementById('myTextBox').addEventListener('input', function() { math.CalculateFactorial(this); });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myTextBox" placeholder="Fatorial">
<div id="title"></div>
```